# Mock camera using video file in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to run functional tests on an Android app that logs in users using facial recognition. The intent is to run these tests automatically so we are using Java 11, Cucumber and the Appium server. The IDE is IntelliJ. For now we are using real devices on local machines.
The ideal scenario is to be able to use a video file instead of the device's camera itself.
How can we mock the camera in order for this to work?

Comment: Any luck? Do you have a solution for this?